# Zoom in mobile webpage?

Tags: html, mobile, viewport

Okay this makes a mobile webpage not be able to zoom:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
```

Now how do I make it be able to zoom?

Comment: My gut feeling? Remove that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value of maximun-scale.